# How to understand "Replaces" field in output of "apt-cache depends"?

Tags: debian, apt

When I run `apt-cache depends tar` under my Debian 8.3 installation, then it says that it will replace [cpio](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/):

```
# apt-cache depends tar
tar
  PreDepends: libacl1
  PreDepends: libc6
  PreDepends: libselinux1
  Suggests: bzip2
  Suggests: ncompress
  Suggests: xz-utils
  Suggests: tar-scripts
  Conflicts: cpio
  Breaks: dpkg-dev
  Replaces: cpio
#
```

However, I have both `cpio` and `tar` packages installed:

```
$ COLUMNS=80 dpkg -l cpio tar
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  cpio           2.11+dfsg-5  amd64        GNU cpio -- a program to manage a
ii  tar            1.28-2.1     amd64        GNU version of the tar archiving
```

(edited by cas: the version Martin has installed is `2.11+dfsg-4.1+deb8u1` rather than the `2.11+dfsg-5` I have from debian `sid`, but it makes no difference.  Faheem's answer is still correct for the same reason)

How to understand the `Replaces:` field in output of `apt-cache depends`?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is missing some information.

```
apt-cache show tar 

Package: tar
Version: 1.28-2.1
[snip]
Replaces: cpio (<< 2.4.2-39)
[snip]
Conflicts: cpio (<= 2.4.2-38)

Package: tar
Source: tar (1.27.1-2)
Version: 1.27.1-2+b1
[snip]
Replaces: cpio (<< 2.4.2-39)
[snip]
Conflicts: cpio (<= 2.4.2-38)
```

Notice that it says it replaces `cpio` for version `<< 2.4.2-39`.
Similarly for conflicts.
Now, I also have `cpio` installed.

```
apt-cache policy cpio

cpio:
  Installed: 2.11+dfsg-4.1+deb8u1
  Candidate: 2.11+dfsg-4.1+deb8u1
  Version table:
     2.11+dfsg-5 0
         50 tor+http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.11+dfsg-4.1+deb8u1 0
        500 tor+http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.11+dfsg-4.1 0
        500 tor+http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

But the versions are much larger than `2.4.x`. This is some ancient issue that could probably be dropped from the current `tar`. Feel free to file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

"Replaces" are packages that will have one or more files replaced by the package you are searching on. For even more detail, see the Debian policy guide: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-replaces